# Await Doesn't Work with Coroutine Assigned to Variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Why in Python (3.6) does

```
chunk = await evt_loop.run_in_executor(io_exec, arc.read, chunk_size)
```

work exactly as expected but

```
read_ftr = evt_loop.run_in_executor(io_exec, arc.read, chunk_size)
chunk = await read_ftr
```

throws AssertionError("yield from wasn't used with future",) on the second line, and how do I get it to work?

The following is the snippet of code I'm trying to run. Fusing the three read_ftr lines together to get the first single-line implementation works, while the way it is below throws that assertion error at "chunk = await read_ftr".

```
read_ftr: aio.Future = None
hash_ftr: aio.Future = None
chunk = None

with open(arc_path, "rb") as arc:
    while arc_offs < arc_size:
        chunk_size = min(arc_size - arc_offs, max_chunk_size)

        if read_ftr:
            chunk = await read_ftr
        read_ftr = evt_loop.run_in_executor(io_exec, arc.read, chunk_size)
        arc_offs += chunk_size

        if not chunk:
            continue

        if hash_ftr:
            await hash_ftr
        hash_ftr = hasher.async_update(chunk)

if hash_ftr:
    await hash_ftr
await hasher.async_digest()
```

Comment: The two snippets should be 100% equivalent. Can you construct a minimal example that demonstrates the assertion you see?

Comment: Splitting `chunk = await run_in_executor(...)` into the three lines shown above isn't equivalent code - the longer version postpones `arc.read` invocation for the next loop iteration, until after the call to `async_update`. Maybe that's what causes the problem? It's really hard to tell based on your example which, while _minimal_, is not _runnable_, so we can't replicate your result.

Comment: Try to place `print(type(read_ftr))` before `chunk = await read_ftr` line. It'll help to see what happens.

Answer (score -2):

When you declare a variable as you did `foo_var = coroutine(args)` you are actually calling the function right then and applying its result to the variable. To pass the function as the variable, do it as `foo_var = coroutine` and then later call it with `foo_var(args)` any time you add parenthesis next to a function it will attempt to call and run that function (even if its a coroutine/ async function)

Comment: This is incorrect - invoking a coroutine function does **not** "run" the function, it just creates and returns a coroutine object. For the code inside the coroutine to execute, this object must be passed to an event loop, or awaited by another coroutine.